# How to find a compatible upgrade for a phone camera

Tags: camera, android

I have a set of [Android video glasses](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VISION-800-Smart-Android-WiFi-Video-Glasses-80-Virtual-Wide-Screen-5MP-Camera/353089293548) which are based on the PRIXTON C18 phone. I'd like to upgrade the camera to a better one - specifically one that supports changing the shutter speed as the current one does not.

I've tried a couple of different cameras from Ebay that look similar to the socket (right shape/number of pins) however they have all been too big or small to click in. Here's what the socket and old camera look like:

[image: Camera socket on device]
Socket on the android device

[image]
Camera

My specific questions are:

1. Is the socket type shown above a standard socket and if so what do I need to search for to find cameras which will be compatible?
2. If the socket type is standard, is it a plug-and-play type thing - i.e. will all camera devices that fit the socket likely just work?

Comment: Your question might be voted to for to be closed as shopping questions are not allowed by the community guidelines. I think you will need to be more concrete about where you get stuck in the process.

Comment: Questions relating to the design of off-the-shelf electronics without the support of a decent schematic will be judged to be off-topic on this site (especially items that have no provenance such as those bought from peebay, shamazon, bang-bad and mali-express).

Comment: *"is it a plug-and-play type thing - i.e. will all camera devices that fit the socket likely just work"* It's very unlikely that it is based on some standard. The best bet you would have is to try to find one from the same manufacturer, although I'm fairly certain that the camera board and it's mating side are custom implementations for the device you have... The sockets are pretty standard, however the use of the pins is not, and plugging in random boards that "fit" will likely end up destroying one or both devices.

Comment: If cell phone cameras were easily replaceable and interchangeable, wouldn't it be expected an active market of camera replacement, with advertisements, how-to webpages, with vendors and sellers trying to convince the consummers to replace the stock camera in their phones with a more advanced one? The reason why there is not such a market is the simple fact that **cell phone cameras are not easily interchangeable with another model.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the socket type shown above a standard socket and if so what do I need to search for to find cameras which will be compatible?

No, at least not as far as I'm aware of.

> If the socket type is standard, is it a plug-and-play type thing - i.e. will all camera devices that fit the socket likely just work?

even if it was, no, that's not how it works: you'd need to know the specific properties of each camera module. This isn't the cozy world of UVC USB webcams that "just work" because there's only a handful of profiles, and the camera reports its resolution and modes it supports itself.

Instead, this is probably a CSI2 camera, where you have variable number of lanes, bit rates, pixel formats, line reading orders, timings...

So, you need to modify your smartphone operating system to drive the new instead of the old camera (if your smartphone SoC can do that at all, even if the pinout is the same).

In short: no, you can't just upgrade a camera from a highly customized device like a smartphone without nearly design-level insights. I'm sure people have done it, but it's not within what I'd expect you'd be able to do without dedicated expensive measurement equipment, and an in-depth knowledge of how to modify your smart phone operating system image.